# Need to get clarity on cvxpy problem solver

Tags: cvxpy

Recently started working on cvxpy problem solver (SVM SOCP) and everytime when I run, I am getting different answers. Do we need to define random_state here also or what is the best way to define this?

Note that for getting SOCP constraints, we have to take square root of semidefinite matrix (covariance). For this we are following LDL decomposition.

Comment: There are multiple solvers and you did not say which one you were using. While indeterminismn might be possible for some solvers / configs, chances are, that the source of indeterminism is on your end. A lot more information would be needed for careful debugging. Keep in mind, that multicore + floating-point alone is a source of indeterminism (in general) but your observation sounds much more severe, indicating some other problem or severe numerical-trouble.

Comment: First figure out if the solver is getting  exactly the same problem each time. Some of the cvxpy solvers can save the data file of the problem they are getting from cvxpy just before they start optimizing. Then you know better which side (your input/cvxpy/solver) is to blame.